# LLBLGen Pro with Entity Framework 4?

Tags: .net, orm, entity-framework-4, llblgen

I am doing a small study about what ORM to use for our next project. I have narrowed down to LLBLGen Pro / EF4.

**My question is:** I am more convinced about EF4. Should we use EF4 alone or should we purchase LLBLGen Pro and select EF4 as target framework? Are there any advantages/disadvantages in doing so?

Any guidance/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLBLGen Pro v3 offers both, and you can switch between frameworks at any time (give or take the differences of course you have to fix, e.g. our runtime doesn't support valuetype definitions (Complex types in EF jargon), e.g. 'Address' with its own fields which is used as type of a field. This is supported in the designer and for EF.

Our designer is much more advanced than EF's native designer. See for a non-conclusive list why: http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2010/05/09/why-llblgen-pro-v3-0-is-better-than-the-regular-designer-for-ef-v4-0.aspx